# GZIP usage in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, zlib

I am using this [NSData+GZIP.swift](https://github.com/1024jp/NSData-GZIP?files=1) library to zip/unzip data from server and here is process how to use it:

1. Add `NSData+GZIP.swift` file to your project.
2. Add `libz.dylib` library to your project.
3. Add a line `#include <zlib.h>` to your `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` file.
4. Invoke from your Swift/ObjC files.

But somehow `libz.dylib` is not working fine and I am getting 21 errors such as:

> use of unresolved identifier 'z_stream'

Has anyone encountered the same?

Comment: Did you correctly added the include in your bridging header? I know you listed it in the third step, but did you double-check that you've done it properly?

Comment: Yes i  have added 
#ifndef BusinessCard_BusinessCard_Bridging_Header_h
#define BusinessCard_BusinessCard_Bridging_Header_h

#include <zlib.h>

#endif

Answer (score 0):

ha, the problem is that you haven't create ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h file correctly.

How to do:
1.Click File>New>File
2.Then select iOS/Source/**Objective-C File**
3.Specify the name 
4.Select the location
5.Click Create button, then, a popup message will raise to create a bridge
6.Please click YES
7.then, Add a line #include  to your ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h file.
8.you will find it works!!!!
btw, then, you can delete the .m file which is for OC.